# Having problems with the 'after' command

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to python and was currently working on a project when the `after` command failed to run. I tried to fix it by putting `root=Tk()` at the top to account for the `root.after` but that made the buttons completely useless.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import random
import time

root=Tk()

class Game:

    def __init__(self,master):

        self.Title=ttk.Label(master,text='BLOODBORNE')
        self.Title.grid(row=0,columnspan=2)

        self.GameStartButton=ttk.Button(master,text='Start Game',command=self.Gameloop)
        self.GameStartButton.grid(row=1,columnspan=2)
        self.SettingsButton=ttk.Button(master,text='Settings',command=self.Settings)
        self.SettingsButton.grid(row=2,column=0)
        self.CreditsButton=ttk.Button(master,text='Credits',command=self.Credits)
        self.CreditsButton.grid(row=2,column=1)

    def Gameloop(self):
        self.Title.config(text='GAME NOT YET FINISHED')
        root.after(3000,self.Gameloop)
        self.Title.config(text='BLOODBORNE')

    def Settings(self):
        self.GameStartButton.grid_remove()
        root.after(3000,self.Settings)
        self.GameStartButton.grid(row=1,columnspan=2)

    def Credits(self):
        self.GameStartButton.grid_remove()
        root.after(3000,self.Credits)
        self.GameStartButton.grid(row=1,columnspan=2)

def main():

    app=Game(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__" : main()
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Update: The buttons are working, but the `after` command is not doing what I intended. I need help finding a way to delay the code lines.

Update II: Thank you for the comments. I now know what I did wrong. If you wish to suggest ways to change my code, by all means, go ahead. If not, thank you again for the help.

Comment: Why do you think the after command is failing to run? It seems to run for me just fine when I click any of the buttons. Though, I'm not quite sure why you're using `after` since the "loops" don't do any thing useful.

Comment: @BryanOakley The buttons aren't performing their actions. And the after is to add a time pause in between the codes so that I can see the codes execute properly. The idea is that I would continue developing the code after I make sure that the `after` works. Plus, I was testing `grid_remove()` hence the different codes.

Comment: The buttons in this example work for me. Are you sure that _this_ code does what you claim? Have you tried adding a `print` statement inside each function that is called from a button? I don't see anything about the code that would prevent those functions from being called.

Comment: `root.after` does not do a 3-second delay.  You CAN'T do a delay in the middle of a GUI callback -- your GUI would freeze.  It queues up a message that causes the function to get called 3 seconds later.  So, you will never see "GAME NOT YET FINISHED", because you immediately overwrite it with "BLOODBORNE".

Comment: @BryanOakley Thank you for the input. I realised that the buttons are working. However, do you have any idea why the `after` is not stalling the lines of code?

Comment: @TimRoberts Any idea how I could stall the code?

Comment: `after` won't stall the code in the way you're using it. It adds something to a queue, but then the rest of the function continues on, by design.

Comment: You CAN'T stall the code.  That's not how you program an event-driven GUI.  Your `self.title.Config` won't even take effect until your handler returns and the event loop can dispatch the request.  You have to make your change, then use `root.after` to call a DIFFERENT function that changes the string back.

Comment: Thank you @TimRoberts It seems that I have a lot more research to do then.

Comment: @TimRoberts: actually, you can stall the code, just not in the way the OP is doing it. However, it's not recommended since you can easily end up with multiple event loops nested inside each other. [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76070083/7432) shows how to do it.

Comment: Just because it is possible does not mean it is good practice.  What you have described is not the right way to do what he wants to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on comments to the question, it appears that you want the code that appears after you call `after` to not run until the delay has expired. That is not how `after` is designed to work. Once you've called `after` in the way that you're calling it, the rest of the function will continue to execute. Only the code you included as part of the call to `after` will run after the delay.

One way to do what you want is to use `wait_variable`, which will pause execution of the function until a tkinter variable is set. You can then use `after` to set that variable at some point in the future.

In the time between calling `after` and the expiration of the time period, tkinter will still be able to service events. However, you must be fairly careful with this since, for example, the user could click on the button again in that interval, causing a second pause nested inside the first.

Here's a simple example:

```
def Gameloop(self):
    self.Title.config(text='GAME NOT YET FINISHED')
    var = IntVar(value=0)
    print("before waiting...")
    root.after(3000, var.set, 1)
    root.wait_variable(var)
    print("after waiting...")
    self.Title.config(text='BLOODBORNE')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really wasn't expecting a lot of help when I started using this site. Thank you for the warning, too.